# Can someone tell me why this React Router structure doesn't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm trying to practice with react routing, so I made this little web app based on geography. First I set up the router paths:

```
import { StrictMode } from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import World from "./World.js";
import Europe from "./Europe.js";
import Britian from "./Britian.js";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
const root = createRoot(rootElement);

root.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<World />}>
        <Route path="europe" element={<Europe />}>
          <Route path="britian" element={<Britian />} />
        </Route>
      </Route>
    </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>
);
```

Here is the starting page:

```
import { Outlet, Link } from "react-router-dom";
    
export default function World() {
  return (
    <>
      <Link to="europe">Europe</Link>
    </>
  );
}
```

But when I click on Europe, the url changes in the address bar, but I don't see the `Europe` component, which looks like this:

```
import { Outlet, Link } from "react-router-dom";

export default function Europe() {
  return (
    <>
      <Link to="britian">Britian</Link>
    </>
  );
}
```

Instead it just seems to stay on the `World` component. What's the deal?

Comment: Which version of React Router are you using?

Answer (score 2):

`<Route path="/" element={<World />}> ... </Route>` is a layout route with nested routes, `World` necessarily should render an `Outlet` for the nested routes to render their `element` content into. The same goes for `Europe` and the layout route it is rendered as.

Update the `World` and `Europe` layout route components to render `Outlet` components for their nested children routes.

```
import { Outlet, Link } from "react-router-dom";
    
export default function World() {
  return (
    <>
      <Link to="europe">Europe</Link>
      <Outlet />
    </>
  );
}
```

```
import { Outlet, Link } from "react-router-dom";

export default function Europe() {
  return (
    <>
      <Link to="britian">Britian</Link>
      <Outlet />
    </>
  );
}
```

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<World />}>
      <Route
        path="europe"
        element={<Europe />}    // rendered into World's outlet
      >
        <Route
          path="britian"
          element={<Britian />} // rendered into Europe's outlet
        />
      </Route>
    </Route>
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

For more details see:

- [Layout Routes](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/concepts#layout-routes)
- [Outlets](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/concepts#outlets)